# In the governments of the Reconstruction South, were Blacks in government always under the control of Whites?

Tags: government, civil-war, reconstruction

I believe that in most cases they were figureheads but were there any examples of an African-American leader who actually was at least partially effective in state government?

EDIT: It is clear that in at least one example, the person in office was quite active and perhaps this is generally the case?

EDIT: State or Federal government, did not mean to be specific to state.

Answer (score 5):

How about [Hiram Rhodes Revels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiram_Rhodes_Revels):

> Hiram Rhodes Revels (September 27, 1827[note 1] – January 16, 1901)
>   was an American politician, a minister in the African Methodist
>   Episcopal Church (AME), and a college administrator. Born free in
>   North Carolina, he later lived and worked in Ohio, where he voted
>   before the Civil War. He became the first African American to serve as
>   a Republican in the U.S. Congress when he was ***elected to the United
>   States Senate to represent Mississippi in 1870 and 1871 during the
>   Reconstruction era***.

Looks like a typical political career to me.

> In his maiden speech to the Senate on March 16, 1870, he argued for
>   the reinstatement of the black legislators of the Georgia General
>   Assembly, who had been illegally ousted by white Democratic Party
>   representatives.

and

> He served on both the Committee of Education and Labor and the
>   Committee on the District of Columbia. (At the time, the Congress
>   administered the District.) Much of the Senate's attention focused on
>   Reconstruction issues. While Radical Republicans called for continued
>   punishment of ex-Confederates, Revels argued for amnesty and a
>   restoration of full citizenship, provided they swore an oath of
>   loyalty to the United States.

So I would say he qualified as 'not a figurehead', but just a typical Senator doing his job, who happened to be African-American.

Comment: Are there examples of his, for example, speaking on the floor?

Comment: I see that in fact he was active in non-trivial ways. The South treated him badly.

Comment: Yes, edited more into answer

Comment: This is very interesting, but the question asks about "Blacks in *state* government".

Comment: I'm not blaming you because you were just quoting Wikipedia, but "first African American to serve ***as a Republican*** in the U.S. Congress"? He was the first African American, period; no African American was elected to Congress as a Democrat until 1934.

Comment: @bof: i don't know why i specified state, i did not mean to.

Comment: The state part was edited into your question by someone else.

Comment: @user2448131: I made that edit. Most "carpetbagger" governments were state govcernments. I did not realize that the OP was also interested in the federal level because blacks were less likely to be "under" whites at that level. I removed that change so you are fine.

Comment: @ Tom Au I wasn't worried about it. I figured you were trying to make the question a little more focused.

Comment: @TomAu The heading still refers to governments of "the Reconstruction South". I wouldn't have thought that included the federal government in Washington, D.C. The District may be kind of Southern, but it didn't secede, so it wasn't under Reconstruction.

Comment: @bof: I agree with you. But the change caused so much confusion that I restored the status quo ante.